# SystemJS newModule() with class (function), not object

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I have some global classes(JS classes with prototype syntax) that need to be manually added to registry with System.set(moduleName, Module). Since second parameter is of type Module, I need to use System.newModule(object).

But, if I pass a non-object to System.newModule(), it throws - Uncaught TypeError: Expected object.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.set(System.normalizeSync('./something'), System.newModule({
  __useDefault: function() {
      console.log('do stuff');
  }
}));
```

Basically all you need to do is to have your function/non-object defined in defalut key and use option: __useDefault: true